# connection string is not correct, how to fix it?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm using visual studio 2017 community and i'm trying to create local data base and I have a problem in the **connection string** since it dont connect when run it step by step its stuck in conn.Open();

this is the code of the connection and the executenonquery:

```
           try
            {
                 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                    AttachDbFilename=C:\USERS\OZ\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2017\PROJECTS\SHILOVI2R\SHILOVI2R\PHONENUM.MDF;
                    Integrated Security=True;
                    Connect Timeout=30;
                    User Instance=True");

                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into phonebook(שם,עיר,כתובת,מספר טלפון,אזור,מספר זיהוי,מחוז,נפה,דת)VALUES('" + rows[0] + "','" + rows[1] + "','" + rows[2] + "','" + rows[3] + "','" + rows[4] + "','" + rows[5] + "','" + rows[6] + "','" + rows[7] + "','" + rows[8] + "') ", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("middle2", "SHILOVI2R", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                Console.WriteLine("Inserting Data Successfully");
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("dont_work", "SHILOVI2R", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Occre while creating table:" + e.Message + "\t" + e.GetType());
            }
```

image screenshot of visual:

[image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNSIi.png)

The entire code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strFilePat = @"C:\Users\oz\Desktop\sql\backup\tabel3.csv";
        ConvertCSVtoDataTable(strFilePat, strFilePat);
    }

    public static DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable(string strFilePath, string conLocoldbString1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("start", "SHILOV", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFilePath))
        {
            string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(header);
            }
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {

                string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = rows[i];
                }
                try
                {
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
                        AttachDbFilename=C:\USERS\OZ\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2017\PROJECTS\SHILOV\SHILOV\LOCALDBSHILOV.MDF;
                        Integrated Security=True;
                        Connect Timeout=30;
                        User Instance=True");

                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into PhoneTable(??,???,?????,???? ?????,????,???? ?????,????,???,??)VALUES('" + rows[0] + "','" + rows[1] + "','" + rows[2] + "','" + rows[3] + "','" + rows[4] + "','" + rows[5] + "','" + rows[6] + "','" + rows[7] + "','" + rows[8] + "') ", conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("middle", "SHILOVI2R", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    Console.WriteLine("Inserting Data Successfully");
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("dont_work", "SHILOVI2R", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception Occre while creating table:" + e.Message + "\t" + e.GetType());
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("finish", "SHILOVI2R", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return dt;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In your screen shot the connection string is totally different (it is a filepath not a connection string). That one surely will fail, the one posted in your code will give you a detailed exception message if any. What is the "connectionstring" used?

Comment: i want to connect to localdb table named phonebook the PHONENUM is the data base ---> this is the path::::--> C:\USERS\OZ\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2017\PROJECTS\SHILOV\SHILOV\LOCALDBSHILOV.MDF

Comment: You may exhausted ADO.NET connection pool. It's costly and inefficient to open SqlConnection on every insert. Try organizing you code, so it will only execute the SqlCommand INSERT in the loop and the rest will be outside. (That's include also putting it outside while)

Answer (score 0):

Use the connection string available in properties tab of the screenshot you have attached if the problem is of connection string
[This is what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEnl1.png) 
Use this as connection string, also remember to replace password value from '*' to actual value.

Comment: you meen this: C:\USERS\OZ\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2017\PROJECTS\SHILOV\SHILOV\LOCALDBSHILOV.MDF since i try to write it like this and it didnt open the localdb also ---> SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"C:\USERS\OZ\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2017\PROJECTS\SHILOV\SHILOV\LOCALDBSHILOV.MDF");